# The completeness and timeliness of server logging on Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need complete access log of my static html object on storage.
In case of AWS S3, it is not guaranteeing the completeness.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#LogDeliveryBestEffort

Does GSC guarantee the completeness of access log?
I could not find out a document about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to [access logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs) as linked in Alex' response: in practice, the generated csv logs are almost always complete and delivered in a timely manner, but strictly speaking neither is guaranteed. Timeliness is already mentioned in the docs, I'll see if we can clarify completeness as well.

Comment: The docs have been updated to call this our more clearly. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Great!
Thank you for letting know it.

Comment: No problem. Do you mind resolving the question / accepting an answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

GCS does offer [access logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs), although they arrive as CSV files with a bunch of information. I'm testing this feature because I've never used before, but it seems that guarantee the completeness of access logs.

To enable the access logs to your bucket.

**First**, create another bucket to hold the access logs. Let's call it "mylogsbucket".

**Second**, give GCS permission to write logs to that bucket with this gsutil command:

gsutil acl ch -g cloud-storage-analytics@google.com:W gs://mylogsbucket

**Third**, activate logging:

gsutil logging set on -b gs://mylogsbucket gs://mybucket
Usage logs for mybucket will now show up about once per hour in mylogsbucket, and storage logs recording how much data is being stored will show up once per day.

More documentation on this feature is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs)

Comment: The docs say nothing about completeness of GCS csv access logs -- it only mentions that timeliness is not guaranteed